# Usando .Zip o linq en c# para sumar dos campos de una serie de objetos contenidos en dos listas

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Tengo una lista de objetos

```
List<Objeto> lista1;
List<Objeto> lista1;
```

Objeto tiene una atributo `X` y un atributo `Y`.

Quiero hacer lo siguiente:

`List<Objeto> listaSuma =>`  sumar los valores `Y` de cada objeto y retornar esto a la nueva lista de objetos (`objeto { X , Y + Y)`).

Obviamente con un bucle `for` ya la he hecho. Quiero usar `Linq` o `Zip`, pero no sé cómo.

PD (los objetos tienen más variables, pero no se tiene que hacer nada con ellas)

```
List<Coordenadas> result = new List<Coordenadas>();
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
  {
     objetAux = new Coordenadas();
     objetAux.Y = list1[i].Y + list12[i].Y;
     objetAux.X = list1[i].X;
     result.Add(objetAux);
  }
```

Comment: ¿`list1` y `list12` son 2 listas distintas? ¿Y ambos siempre tienen la misma cantidad de elementos?

Comment: si, son listas distintas, contienen el mismo número de Xs, lo que quiero es saber que métodos nuevos son mas eficientes que ese for O(n) y de no serlo, aprender a usar nuevas funciones del lenguaje, que nunca está de más

Answer (score 1):

Si te entiendo correctamente, lo único que tienes que hacer es un select generando cada objeto como quieres, algo asi:

```
List<objeto> listaSuma = lista1.Select(l => new objeto() { x=l.x, y=l.y + l.y })
                              .ToList<objeto>();
```

**Edit**

Como comentas que `objeto` tiene mas propiedades, probablemente lo que necesites sea una lista usando un nuevo tipo anonimo. Este sería el código:

```
var listaSuma = lista1.Select(l => new { x=l.x, y=l.y + l.y }).ToList();
```

**Edit 2**

En tu pregunta inicial no entendí bien lo que querias. Si lo que necesitas es unir las dos listas,efectivamente puedes usar [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) (a partir de Net 4.0) y hacer lo siguiente:

```
var listaSuma  = lista1.Zip(lista2, (primero, segundo) => 
                          new { x = primero.x, y = primero.y + segundo.y }).ToList();
```

Comment: pero no usas las dos listas?

porque debería ser y = lista1.y + lista2.y no se si me explico

Comment: Vale,con tu edición ahora lo entiendo, ante no estaba claro. Ahora edito mi respuesta

Comment: @JesúsÁlvarez mira mi segunda edición,espero que sea lo que necesitabas

Comment: Perfecto!!! justo lo que quería probar, no obstante es más lento RunTime 0,0053 for RunTime 0,1194 zip muchas gracias

Comment: @JesúsÁlvarez la implementación de los métodos de linq no es que sean especialmente eficientes. Son una manera de simplificar el código. Me alegro de que te sirviera.

Answer (score 1):

En efecto, puedes usar [`Zip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) para combinar ambas listas con el resultado deseado:

```
List<Coordenadas> result = 
    list1.Zip(
        list12,
        (primero, segundo) =>
            new Coordenadas
            {
                Y = primero.Y + segundo.Y,
                X = primero.X
            }).ToList();
```

Aunque la sintaxis está interesante, no esperes que el rendimiento vaya a ser mejor que el bucle que ya tienes.

Comment: Efectivamente, estoy de acuerdo contigo. Dudo que Zip vaya a ser mas eficiente que un bucle normal. La única ventaja para mi es la simplicidad del comando.

Comment: Perfecto!!! justo lo que quería probar, no obstante es más lento
RunTime 0,0053 for

RunTime 0,1194 zip

muchas gracias